# Ugly orange triangle in the airline theme using nvim

Tags: neovim, plugin-airline

I have an ugly orange triangle appearing in the airline bar in my nvim regardless of the theme I use. Take a look at that :

[image: Look at the right side on the airline bar]

Shocking, isn't it ? Now do you have an idea on how to correct this ?

Comment: High possibility this is because of this issue: https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/157

Comment: @tokoyami I don't understand, do they give a solution in this issue ?

Comment: There is a workaround, [bling's second comment](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/157#issuecomment-22912232). I don't know much about the status line configuration of airline though so I can't tell exactly how to apply it. If noone decides to tackle it, I can probably try during the weekend.

Answer (score 3):

The orange section by default should be the warning one:

> let g:airline_section_warning (ycm_warning_count, whitespace)

You can find a list of all sections at the end of the 'CUSTOMIZATION' section of the airline help (`:help airline-customization`).

It gets filled usually by the whitespace extension which is on by default.

Use the following in you vimrc file to "close" the section. I added the error section too, because it shows on my system so it might on yours in time (if you are using an older version at the moment):

```
let g:airline_section_warning = ''
let g:airline_section_error = ''
```

**This fully disables the section so you won't be seeing anything in it.** I think this is what the issue I linked in the comments is about: hiding the section when no information is available and showing it when there is. Currently you seem to get only one of them.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Christian Brabandt](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/1172#issuecomment-219304788) this is how airline works. He created a solution that requires setting the variable
    `let g:airline_skip_empty_sections = 1`.

Comment: that is correct.